# use both CPU and GPU on google colab parallelly, using TensofFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory, mergesort

I had single file ,say 10Million floating point numbers inside. Using mergesort(custome code below), i would like to sort this file. Here, i am reading 1Million at a time and sorting numbers and writing into a separate file to be merged later.

Custome Mergesort code below using TensorFlow 2.0 API.

```
import tensorflow as tf
#@tf.function
def split_list(input_list):
    input_list_len = len(input_list)
    midpoint = input_list_len // 2
    return input_list[:midpoint], input_list[midpoint:]

#@tf.function
def merge_sorted_lists(list_left, list_right):

    if tf.math.equal(len(list_left), 0) :
        return list_right
    elif tf.math.equal(len(list_right), 0):
        return list_left
    
 
    index_left = index_right = 0
    list_merged = []  # list to build and return
    list_len_target = len(list_left) + len(list_right)
    while tf.math.less(len(list_merged), list_len_target):
        if tf.math.less_equal(list_left[index_left], list_right[index_right]) :
            # Value on the left list is smaller (or equal so it should be selected)
            list_merged = [*list_merged,list_left[index_left]]
            index_left += 1
        else:
            # Right value bigger
            list_merged = [*list_merged,list_right[index_right]]
            index_right += 1
            

        if tf.math.equal(index_right, len(list_right)):
            list_merged = [*list_merged,*list_left[index_left:]]
            break
        elif tf.math.equal(index_left, len(list_left)):
            list_merged = [*list_merged,*list_right[index_right:]]
            break
    return list_merged

#@tf.function
def merge_sort(input_list):
    if tf.math.less_equal(len(input_list), 1):
        return input_list
    else:
        left, right = split_list(input_list)
        return merge_sorted_lists(merge_sort(left), merge_sort(right))
```

Below code calls above merge_sort function on the required host/device.

```
def cpu(input_list):
  lines = []
  with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    lines = merge_sort(input_list)
    lines1 = []
    lines1 = [str(x)+"\n" for x in lines]
  return lines1

def GPU(input_list):
  lines = []
  with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    lines = merge_sort(input_list)
    lines1 = []
    lines1 = [str(x)+"\n" for x in lines]
  return lines1
```

The bove CPU or GPU functions are invoked as below, using iterators to read 1Million at a time:

```
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset("numbers.txt") #10 million rows in single file
dataset = dataset.batch(1_000_000)  # divide into 10 batches of 1million each
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.strip(x), tf.float32))
iterator = dataset.__iter__()
    
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
lines = cpu(np.stack(list(iterator.get_next())))
print(lines)
print("cpu_time ", timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
lines = GPU(np.stack(list(iterator.get_next())))
print(lines)
print("gpu_time ", timeit.default_timer() - start_time)

fid = 1
f_out = open('chunk_{}.txt'.format(fid), 'w')
f_out.writelines(lines)
```

The above code is run **Google Colab GPU instance**, first 1Million records are sorted on CPU once and second million on GPU. However i would like to use both CPU and GPU parallely to run mergesort on different sets of million numbers. Ignore merging for now.
I would appreciate, sample code lines(if there exists, few lines) or guide(if lot of work involved), to acheive this.

Comment: Use Tensorflow [distribution strategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training) library to run your code parallel on different runtime(GPU,CPU). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute training among multiple GPUs, multiple machines, or TPUs with a built-in distribution strategy.

The MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy is the one you are looking for. It has two implementations for cross-device communications. CommunicationImplementation.RING is RPC-based and supports both CPU and GPU.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/experimental/CommunicationImplementation#RING